# One Certificate for all instances in XP Scaled Installation - xDB Forbidden issue

Tags: xdb, xconnect, experience-analytics, scaling

I did an on-premise setup for Sitecore 9.3 XP Scaled environment. At the time of installation I created separate certificates using `createcert.json` file and common `xconnect` certificate thumbprint for all the instances.

Now going forward in production (which is also an On-Premise environment) we have to use one certificate provided by our IT team.

I did an installation with this single certificate thumbprint for all instances including `xconnect`. So here are my installation instances.

This certificate subject identifier is defined as `uatcm.company.com`

```
uatcm.company.com:433 (CM)
uatcm.company.com:1221 (xconnect collection)
uatcm.company.com:1222 (xconnect collection search)
uatcm.company.com:1223 (xconnect marketing automation)
uatcm.company.com:1224 (xconnect marketing automation report)
uatcm.company.com:1225 (processing)
uatcm.company.com:1226 (reporting)
uatcm.company.com:1227 (reference data)
uatcm.company.com:1228 (cortex processing)
uatcm.company.com:1229 (cortex reporting)
```

I have installed the CD instance and the 4 necessary certificates including thumbprint in connectionstring.config **in CD machine and I am able to connect to these services with https.**

My question is - **is this a valid setup (using port numbers) ?** If we need to create separate bindings so can we add these domains in one certificate and use it for all?

**Right now I am getting FORBIDDEN 403 issue when I browse for Experience Analytics in my CM instance**

Comment: Using single certificate is fine. But make sure you update the certificate thumbprint in all connection string files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore recommends a separate certificate for each instance to make it more secure and to limit the damage that could be done should a certificate be compromised.

That being said, I believe it is still valid to use a single certificate on multiple instances. I have seen one single `wildcard certificate` be used for all CM,CD, Proc, Rep and individual XConnect instances.

If you are experiencing issues with 403 forbidden, I recommend that you ensure each sitecore and Xconnect role has permission to access the private key for the certificates that it needs access too.

To do this, run `MMC => navigate to correct certificate store. Right click => Manage private key.`

Make sure for example the iis instance you are using has permission to access.

i.e. `iis apppool\yourapp.cm`

EDIT: apologies I didn't fully read your question regarding port numbers... I think you are over complicating the issue by using port numbers, I think you will come I to problems that way. Instead you could either use single wildcard certificate, or add multiple "subject alternative names" SANs to the same single certificate, and still use the one certificate.

Comment: Thanks Dean. Apologies for late reply. We will try to get the certificate with multiple SANs. I have upvoted and accepted this as answer.